How to stop automatic api callouts?
I have deactivated all the flows and asynchronous jobs, triggers, platform events, no connected apps, apex classes. But still api requests count is being increased. What would be the reason.

The title of the question refers to callouts, i.e. outbound calls. "api request count" can refer to inbound calls. Are you sure you don't mistake the one for the other?

Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].   When you say "api requests count", are you referring to "API Requests, Last 24 Hours" on the Setup > Company Information page?  Please [edit] your post to clarify.

Sorry for the wrong phrases, what i wanted to say is, How to stop automatic api requests. The minute i login to the org, api requests are increasing rapidly without any user interference. I have deactivated all flows, asynchronous jobs, triggers, platform events, connected apps, and Apex classes. However, the API requests continues to increase. What could be the cause of this?

@Vassuuu API requests is also consumed by developer console within salesforce and other developer IDE tool that connects to salesforce. also there maybe some other external app that is calling salesforce, check the salesforce user connection history for more details
